# Curious about possible checkpoint time improvements

Tags: apache-flink

We are currently working on a high-performance Flink job with a very large and complex state. Our primary focus is on achieving high performance, and the job must ensure at least once semantics.

Due to the exceptionally high parallelism of this job (120+ parallelism), we encountered issues with checkpointing, specifically the duration of checkpointing exceeded the acceptable limits, sometimes taking more than 10 hours. After thorough investigation, we discovered a significant key skewness problem, where one task slot was handling 90-95% of the workload, causing the checkpoints to stall.

We resolved this issue by using the `rebalance()` function. Subsequently, we continued to optimize our checkpointing performance, even though the checkpoints are now much faster and acceptable. We came across reports suggesting the use of 10ms checkpointing intervals to reduce checkpoint size via incremental checkpoints. However, we found it impossible to achieve milliseconds intervals as our checkpoints consistently took over 1 second. Consequently, we settled for a 10-second checkpointing interval for comparison, considering we were previously using 10-minute intervals.

My question is: given that the Flink job receives a uniform amount of data continuously, should we have observed more significant changes in checkpointing size and duration when we altered the interval? We only reduced the checkpoint size from 10GB to 2GB by transitioning from a 10-minute interval to a 10-second interval. We also didn't see substantial improvements in terms of checkpointing duration.
And finally, is the suggested configuration for our job to have as big of an interval as possible, since we’re focused on performance and are okay with reprocessing X amount of minutes of data upon failure?

[image]

Comment: With incremental checkpoints, are you using the write-ahead-log-based incremental checkpoints introduced with FLIP-158, or the older scheme? Have you experimented with buffer debloating? https://flink.apache.org/2022/05/30/improving-speed-and-stability-of-checkpointing-with-generic-log-based-incremental-checkpoints/

Comment: No, unfortunately we're are still stuck using Flink 1.14, so I can't experiment with write-ahead-log-based. And yes, we experimented with both unaligned checkpoints and the buffer debloating feature.